# Derivatives-Problem of rate of change

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

I'm studying applications of derivatives and I have the following problem about rate of change:

A raindrop falls over a surface and generated waves of circular form such that the rate of change of the radius of the wave its 636.36 ft/s and expands along 1,1s. Find the area of the circle of maximum radius.

My approach: let's call $r$ the radius then the hypothesis means $v=\frac{dr}{dt}=636.36 ft/s$. By physics we have $r=vt$ then $r=636.36*1,1=700 ft$ is the maximum radius. Then $A=\pi*r^2=\pi*(700)^2=1539380.40 ft^2$.

Is my solution right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed correct.

---

P.S. Since you're solving this in the context of calculus, you may want to do it using principles of calculus (as opposed to algebra).

You had $v = \frac{dr}{dt} = 636.36$, so

$$\mathrm dr = v \, \mathrm dt$$

To get the maximum radius, we want the $r$ that was at the end of the time interval, which was from $t=0$ to $t=1.1$. So integrate (sum) both sides to get

$r = \int_0^{1.1} 636.36 \, \mathrm dt = 636.36x \Big |_0^{1.1} = 636.36(1.1) - 636.36(0) = 700$.

Then continue as you did to get the area.